# Bottom Nav Bar overlaps screen content in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `BottomNavBar` which is called inside the `bottomBar` of a `Scaffold`.
Every screen contains a `LazyColumn` which displays a bunch of images.
For some reason when I finish scrolling, the `BottomNavBar` overlaps the lower part of the items list.
How can I fix this?

[image]

Here the set content of MainActivity

```
SetContent{
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = "tartufozon") },
                actions = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { Timber.d("Mail clicked") }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Default.Email, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                }
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavBar(navController = navController)
        }
    ) {
    BottomNavScreensController(navController = navController)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

As per the [API definition for Scaffold](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#scaffold), your inner content (the trailing lambda you have your `BottomNavScreensController` in), is given a [`PaddingValues`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/PaddingValues.html) object that gives you the right amount of padding for your top app bar, bottom bar, etc.

Right now, you're not referencing that padding at all and hence, your content is *not* padded in. This is what is causing your overlap.

You can add a `Box` around your `BottomNavScreensController` to apply the padding, or pass the padding directly into your `BottomNavScreensController` so that each individual screen can correctly apply the padding; either solution works.

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
      //
    },
    bottomBar = {
        //
    }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        // Apply the padding globally to the whole BottomNavScreensController
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
            BottomNavScreensController(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: consider when BottomBar is clipped with a shape. then the areas of BottomBar that is cut, will be using scaffold's bg color. what I mean is that innerPadding should be applied after content bg color is set. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76914671/jetpack-compose-bottombar-transparent-background-color-when-it-has-rounded-corne

Answer (score 15):

Following [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake)'s answer and its comments and just to save you few minutes. The code would be something like:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
      //
    },
    bottomBar = {
        //
    }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(
          PaddingValues(bottom = innerPadding.calculateBottomPadding()) {
            BottomNavScreensController(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `Modifier.padding(bottom= ...)` instead of specifying zeros

Comment: You're right. Anwser updated. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You no longer need to do any calculations. In the scaffold content, do:

```
content = { padding ->
  Column(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)
  ) {...
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
       BottomNavigationBar(navController = navController)
   }
) { innerPadding ->
      Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
               DestinationsNavHost(
                  navGraph = NavGraphs.root,
                  navController = navController,
                  engine = navHostEngine
                )
         }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add your layouts and views in content with its padding like in the example:

```
Scaffold(
        content = {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {
                //add your layout here
            }

        },
        topBar = { 
                 //your top bar
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
           //your floating action bar
        },
        bottomBar = {
            //your bottom navigation
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved by opening a Box there and giving the paddingValues value I wrote in it.

```
Scaffold(
            bottomBar = {
                BottomBar(navController = navController, bottomBarState = bottomBarState)
            },
            content = {paddingValues->
                Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)){
                    SetupNavGraph(navHostController = navController)
                }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Following [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) answer, if you have a list in your main screen and want to show/hide the bottom bar. It will perform unexpected behavior when you back to list screen (the scroll state is in very bottom) and show the navigation bar.The list item will scroll up a bit which cause the list doesn't fully scrolled to the bottom.

This is because of when you back to the list screen and want to show the bottom bar, the list already there. Then the bottom bar will show and list will not calculate the innerPadding for more.

[image]

To handle this, just pass the innerPadding into the list screen like this:

```
            Scaffold(
                bottomBar = {
                BottomNavBar(navController)
            }) { innerPadding ->
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = MovieListDirections.destination
            ) {
                MovieListDirections.screenWithPaddingBottomBar(
                    this,
                    innerPadding.calculateBottomPadding() // pass here
                )
            }
```

Then in the list screen

```
@Composable
fun MovieListMainView(viewModel: MovieListViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
                  bottomBarHeight: Float) {
    val movieList by viewModel.movieList.collectAsState()
    var navBarHeight by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    if (bottomBarHeight != 0f) {
        navBarHeight = bottomBarHeight
    }

    MovieListLayout().MovieGridLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, navBarHeight.dp),
        movies = movieList.movieList.movieItems,
        onItemClick = {
            viewModel.onMovieClicked(it)
        })
}
```