# hide Top and Bottom Navigator on a specific screen inside Scaffold Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm creating a simple app with bottom navigation and drawer.

I wrap all screens inside a Scaffold with topbar and bottom bar.
I want to hide top bar and bottom bar on a specific screen. Does anyone know to how achieve that

here is the code for setting up navigation.

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed))

Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        AppBottomBar(navController)
    },
    topBar = {
        AppTopBar(scaffoldState)
    },
    drawerContent = {
        DrawerContent(navController, scaffoldState)
    },
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState
) {
    // ovoid bottom bar overlay content
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 58.dp)) {
        AppNavigation(navController)
    }
}
```

`AppNavigation` contains `NavHost` for navigating to screens

Comment: I use multiple NavHostController within the project. I have mainNavController for main screens, like HomeScreen, LoginScreen etc. and in the HomeScreen, I have a Scaffold and NavigationBar, I manage NavigationBar and the home pages (Profile, Search etc.) using another homeNavController defined in the HomeScreen. You may follow that way. Just another point of view.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

for now, I can achieve that by checking current route to show or hide bottomBar, topBar. But I think there's must be better solutions. The way I wrap all screens inside Scaffold might not right.

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed))

Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        if (currentRoute(navController) != "Example Screen") {
            AppBottomBar(navController)
        }
    },
    topBar = {
        AppTopBar(scaffoldState)
    },
    drawerContent = {
        DrawerContent(navController, scaffoldState)
    },
    floatingActionButton = {
        FloatingButton(navController)
    },
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState
) {
    // ovoid bottom bar overlay content
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 58.dp)) {
        AppNavigation(navController)
    }
}

@Composable
public fun currentRoute(navController: NavHostController): String? {
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    return navBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getString(KEY_ROUTE)
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution but please update if you find a better one.  I'm exploring the same issue.

Comment: use `56.dp` to be more precise with material 3 design

Answer (score 61):

I recommend you use `AnimatedVisibility` for `BottomNavigation` widget and `TopAppBar` widget, im my opinion it's clearest way for compose.

1. You should use `remeberSaveable` to store state of BottomBar and TopAppBar:

```
// State of bottomBar, set state to false, if current page route is "car_details"
val bottomBarState = rememberSaveable { (mutableStateOf(true)) }

// State of topBar, set state to false, if current page route is "car_details"
val topBarState = rememberSaveable { (mutableStateOf(true)) }
```

2. In composable function we used `when` for control state of BottomBar and TopAppBar, below we set `bottomBarState` and `topBarState` to `true`, if we would like to show BottomBar and TopAppBar, otherwise we set `bottomBarState` and `topBarState` to `false`:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()

// Subscribe to navBackStackEntry, required to get current route
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()

// Control TopBar and BottomBar
when (navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route) {
    "cars" -> {
        // Show BottomBar and TopBar
        bottomBarState.value = true
        topBarState.value = true
    }
    "bikes" -> {
        // Show BottomBar and TopBar
        bottomBarState.value = true
        topBarState.value = true
    }
    "settings" -> {
        // Show BottomBar and TopBar
        bottomBarState.value = true
        topBarState.value = true
    }
    "car_details" -> {
        // Hide BottomBar and TopBar
        bottomBarState.value = false
        topBarState.value = false
    }
}

com.google.accompanist.insets.ui.Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        BottomBar(
            navController = navController,
            bottomBarState = bottomBarState
        )
    },
    topBar = {
        TopBar(
            navController = navController,
            topBarState = topBarState
        )
    },
    content = {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = NavigationItem.Cars.route,
        ) {
            composable(NavigationItem.Cars.route) {
                CarsScreen(
                    navController = navController,
                )
            }
            composable(NavigationItem.Bikes.route) {
                BikesScreen(
                    navController = navController
                )
            }
            composable(NavigationItem.Settings.route) {
                SettingsScreen(
                    navController = navController,
                )
            }
            composable(NavigationItem.CarDetails.route) {
                CarDetailsScreen(
                    navController = navController,
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
```

**Important:** Scaffold from Accompanist, initialized in build.gradle. We use Scaffold from Accompanist, because we need full control of paddings, for example in default Scaffold from Compose we can't disable padding for content from top if we have TopAppBar. In our case it's required because we have animation for TopAppBar, content should be under TopAppBar and we manually control padding for each pages. Documentation from Accompanist: https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/.

3. Put `BottomNavigation` inside `AnimatedVisibility`, set `visible` value from `bottomBarState` and set `enter` and `exit` animation, in my case I use `slideInVertically` for `enter` animation and `slideOutVertically` for `exit` animation:

```
AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = bottomBarState.value,
        enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
        exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it }),
        content = {
            BottomNavigation {
                val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

                items.forEach { item ->
                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = item.icon),
                                contentDescription = item.title
                            )
                        },
                        label = { Text(text = item.title) },
                        selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(item.route) {
                                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

4. Put `TopAppBar` inside `AnimatedVisibility`, set `visible` value from `topBarState` and set `enter` and `exit` animation, in my case I use `slideInVertically` for `enter` animation and `slideOutVertically` for `exit` animation:

```
AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = topBarState.value,
        enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { -it }),
        exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { -it }),
        content = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = title) },
            )
        }
    )
```

Full code of MainActivity:

```
package codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.animation.ExperimentalAnimationApi
import androidx.compose.animation.slideInVertically
import androidx.compose.animation.slideOutVertically
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavGraph.Companion.findStartDestination
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.currentBackStackEntryAsState
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation.screens.BikesScreen
import codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation.screens.CarDetailsScreen
import codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation.screens.CarsScreen
import codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation.screens.SettingsScreen
import codes.andreirozov.bottombaranimation.ui.theme.BottomBarAnimationTheme

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BottomBarAnimationApp()
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun BottomBarAnimationApp() {

    // State of bottomBar, set state to false, if current page route is "car_details"
    val bottomBarState = rememberSaveable { (mutableStateOf(true)) }

    // State of topBar, set state to false, if current page route is "car_details"
    val topBarState = rememberSaveable { (mutableStateOf(true)) }

    BottomBarAnimationTheme {
        val navController = rememberNavController()

        // Subscribe to navBackStackEntry, required to get current route
        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()

        // Control TopBar and BottomBar
        when (navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route) {
            "cars" -> {
                // Show BottomBar and TopBar
                bottomBarState.value = true
                topBarState.value = true
            }
            "bikes" -> {
                // Show BottomBar and TopBar
                bottomBarState.value = true
                topBarState.value = true
            }
            "settings" -> {
                // Show BottomBar and TopBar
                bottomBarState.value = true
                topBarState.value = true
            }
            "car_details" -> {
                // Hide BottomBar and TopBar
                bottomBarState.value = false
                topBarState.value = false
            }
        }

        // IMPORTANT, Scaffold from Accompanist, initialized in build.gradle.
        // We use Scaffold from Accompanist, because we need full control of paddings, for example
        // in default Scaffold from Compose we can't disable padding for content from top if we
        // have TopAppBar. In our case it's required because we have animation for TopAppBar,
        // content should be under TopAppBar and we manually control padding for each pages.
        com.google.accompanist.insets.ui.Scaffold(
            bottomBar = {
                BottomBar(
                    navController = navController,
                    bottomBarState = bottomBarState
                )
            },
            topBar = {
                TopBar(
                    navController = navController,
                    topBarState = topBarState
                )
            },
            content = {
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = NavigationItem.Cars.route,
                ) {
                    composable(NavigationItem.Cars.route) {
                        // show BottomBar and TopBar
                        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                            bottomBarState.value = true
                            topBarState.value = true
                        }
                        CarsScreen(
                            navController = navController,
                        )
                    }
                    composable(NavigationItem.Bikes.route) {
                        // show BottomBar and TopBar
                        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                            bottomBarState.value = true
                            topBarState.value = true
                        }
                        BikesScreen(
                            navController = navController
                        )
                    }
                    composable(NavigationItem.Settings.route) {
                        // show BottomBar and TopBar
                        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                            bottomBarState.value = true
                            topBarState.value = true
                        }
                        SettingsScreen(
                            navController = navController,
                        )
                    }
                    composable(NavigationItem.CarDetails.route) {
                        // hide BottomBar and TopBar
                        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                            bottomBarState.value = false
                            topBarState.value = false
                        }
                        CarDetailsScreen(
                            navController = navController,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun BottomBar(navController: NavController, bottomBarState: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    val items = listOf(
        NavigationItem.Cars,
        NavigationItem.Bikes,
        NavigationItem.Settings
    )

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = bottomBarState.value,
        enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
        exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it }),
        content = {
            BottomNavigation {
                val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

                items.forEach { item ->
                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = item.icon),
                                contentDescription = item.title
                            )
                        },
                        label = { Text(text = item.title) },
                        selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(item.route) {
                                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun TopBar(navController: NavController, topBarState: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val title: String = when (navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: "cars") {
        "cars" -> "Cars"
        "bikes" -> "Bikes"
        "settings" -> "Settings"
        "car_details" -> "Cars"
        else -> "Cars"
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = topBarState.value,
        enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { -it }),
        exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { -it }),
        content = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = title) },
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Result:

[image: BottomBar and TopBar animation]

Don't forget to use @ExperimentalAnimationApi annotation for compose functions.

**Update:** with Compose version 1.1.0 and above `@ExperimentalAnimationApi` not required.

**22.02.2022 Update:** I made some research, and update point 2. Now we use `when` for control `topBarState` and `bottomBarState`.

Full code available on gitHub:
https://github.com/AndreiRoze/BottomBarAnimation/tree/with_animated_topbar

Examples of animations available in the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers

Comment: Followed this answer but my bottom bar moves laggy, i dont know why

Comment: @ysfcyln hard to answer without code, i tested that example on OnePlus 3, which was produced at 2016, haven't lags.

Comment: I posted it as a question, can you check [it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71170373/5695091).

Comment: what if we use `PaddingValues` from Scaffold's `content`,
then we cant just hide the bottom navigation

Comment: @ysfcyln you see lag because you tested it on debug mode

Comment: if you scroll to the very bottom, the column will be have some weird behavior. It will adjust the height of the bottom navbar again

Comment: @YehezkielL, I checked it right now, behaviour is correct. Also tested with latest versions of compose and libraries - behaviour still correct.

Comment: It only happens if you add innerPadding in the content as bottom bar, like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573601/bottom-nav-bar-overlaps-screen-content-in-jetpack-compose/75223087#75223087

Comment: @YehezkielL, if you would like to use that way, you should control padding separately for each screen.

Comment: In case of topbar, using androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold ([Accompanist Scaffold](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/) is deprecated) will produce a weird effect while performing the exit transition. The topbar seems to wait for the screen to compose, then it starts the exit transition. However,  using `shrinkOut()` in addition to the exit transition code in this answer works nicely.

Answer (score 12):

Easiest solution I found (without animation)

```
fun MainScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val navController = rememberNavController()
    var showBottomBar by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()

    showBottomBar = when (navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route) {
        "RouteOfScreenA" -> false // on this screen bottom bar should be hidden
        "RouteOfScreenB" -> false // here too
        else -> true // in all other cases show bottom bar
    }

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier,
        bottomBar = { if (showBottomBar) MyBottomNavigation(navController = navController) }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        MyNavHost(
            navController = navController,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `compositionlocal`, and as you wrap your mainActivity with the `CompositionLocalProvider`, pass the supportActionBar to your child composable  At the screen where you wish to hide the topBar, invoke the .hide() method
at the top. See below:

```
data class ShowAppBar(val show: ActionBar?)

internal val LocalAppBar = compositionLocalOf<ShowAppBar>{ error("No ActionBar provided") }
```

In mainActivity, pass the ActionBar via

```
val showy = ShowAppBar(show = supportActionBar )
.....

 CompositionLocalProvider(
   LocalAppBar provides showy
  ) {
      YourTheme {
        yourApp()
      }
   }
```

Invoking at the screen >> `LocalAppBar.current.show?.hide()`

Comment: I haven't tested this answer, but it seems way more scalable than other answers.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. You get the current route from the currentRoute function and do a check in your bottombar composable to either hide or show the BottomNavigationView.

```
  @Composable
fun currentRoute(navController: NavHostController): String? {
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    return navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
}

@Composable
fun MainScreenView() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(bottomBar = {
        if (currentRoute(navController) != BottomNavItem.Setup.screen_route)
            BottomNavigation(navController = navController)
    }
    ) {
        NavigationGraph(navController = navController)
    }
}
```