# Jetpack Compose Bottom Navigation Bar visibility changes with delay

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a bottom navigation bar with 3 screen. I am hiding bottom navigation bar in detail screen with `AnimatedVisibility` but visibility changes with delay.

```
        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
            // Get UI state
            val uiState by rememberFlowWithLifecycle(flow = viewModel.uiState).collectAsState(initial = MainUiState(true))
            // Set Status bar to transparent
            SetStatusBarColor()
            // Create Navigation
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            val navigationActions = remember(navController) {
                NavActions(navController)
            }
            // Create Scaffold Composable
            Scaffold(
                topBar = { },
                bottomBar = {
                    AnimatedVisibility(
                        visible = uiState.isBottomBarVisible,
                    ) {
                        BottomNavigationBar(
                            navController,
                            navigationActions,
                            Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()
                        )
                    }
                }
            ) { innerPaddings ->
                NavigationGraph(
                    navController,
                    navigationActions,
                    Modifier
                        .padding(innerPaddings)
                        .statusBarsPadding()
                )
            }
            // Change bottom bar state
            val currentRoute = getCurrentRoute(navController = navController)
            viewModel.changeBottomBarVisibility(currentRoute != Screen.Detail.path)
        }
    }
```

With default enter and exit animation, visibility changes **without** delay
[image: default]

But when I change enter and exit animations for example `scale`, bottom bar has laggy behaviour while becoming invisible

```
AnimatedVisibility(
       visible = uiState.isBottomBarVisible,
       enter = scaleIn(),
       exit = scaleOut()
        ) {
            BottomNavigationBar(
               navController,
               navigationActions,
               Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()
             )
     }
```

[image: scale]

Tested in Huawei P40 Lite and Google Pixel Emulator, behaviours are the same.

Compose version is 1.0.5
Compose navigation version is 2.4.0
Compose animation version is 1.1.0

In short, animated visibility hasn't got smooth behaviour without default animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, it's happens because size of screen changes when you hide bottomBar. For fix that, try to delete modifier `padding(innerPaddings)` in `NavigationGraph` and control padding manually for each pages. If it's doesn't help, i will try your code later.

Comment: Just tested it and you are right, need to pass `innerPaddings` to each screen manually

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by `and control padding manually for each pages`? we are obligated to use Scaffold `innerPaddings` to make everything work, including such cases as paddings for soft keyboard and so on, so what's exactly manually? reimplementing Google logic from scratch somehow?

Comment: @user924, you can try to pass `innerPaddings` to screens which should have padding.

Comment: thanks, yeah, instead of use them for `NavHost` I tried to pass for each screen separately, seems this way we have more control, I fixed the issue with scroll jumping this way when bottom bar visible or invisible for specific screens