# LazyColumn cuts off items when using with BottomNavigationView and Toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose works fine with Scaffold and its inner padding according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66574166/13083841) link. but when I try to use it inside a Fragment, it's items cut off by Toolbar and BottomNavigationView.

should I calculate inner padding manually depending on Toolbar and BottomNavigationViewsize or is there a better solution?

here's the structure. items of lazyColumn are colorful.

[image: picture]

as you can see blue item is cut off.

**update:**
I realized that this behavior is because root of activity is a CoordinatorLayout and my container has **appbar_scrolling_view_behavior**. I tried [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#parent-view-child-compose), but it didn't work.

Comment: @mxrzbn can you please share the piece of code what have you tried?

Comment: it depends on what you do in the fragment. If you put your Toolbar, LazyColumn and BottomNavigation inside one `Column`, there won't be no cut off. If you have those in a Box for some reason, then yes, you will need to position/pad it manually. By the way, what's the reason not to use Scaffold? You can use it inside Fragment too.

Comment: @JanBína I am using single activity + fragments. In my activity I have toolbar + bottomNav + navHostFragment. When I put a composeView inside my fragment and make it match fragment's height, and set a lazyColumn to that composeView, it gets cut off.

Comment: @vivekmodi I added a picture. maybe that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would help, but you can try adding the height of the Bottom Navigation view as a `bottom content padding` to the LazyColumn or to a transparent widget inside another `item{…}` scope.

as a content padding

```
LazyColumn(
      modifier = Modifier
             .fillMaxSize(),
      contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = <Bottom navigation height>)
) {…}
```

or as another item scope

```
LazyColumn(
      modifier = Modifier
             .fillMaxSize()
) {
    items (..) {…}
    
    item {
        Box(
           modifier = Modifier.height(<Bottom navigation view height>)
        )
    }   

}
```

Comment: this is a workaround and if your toolbar and bottomNav do not change, works. but my toolbar height changes in time. plus I think there should be another way, because I think it is a common issue.